# Illegal Data Errors while dealing with Apache Phoenix Boolean Data Types

Tags: boolean, apache-phoenix

When I attempt to Query data from phoenix table as following:

```
SELECT distinct 
"usersFam"."Email" as "Email",
"mediaFam"."Title" as "Name",
"publishedQueueFam"."InSync" as "In Sync",
"publishedQueueFam"."CreationDate" as "Sync_Date",
"mediaDetailsFam"."Duration" as "Duration",
"mediaTypeFam"."ParentDirectory"||'/'||"publishedVersionsFam"."S3InputPath" as "PackageOutput"
from   "media" 
INNER JOIN "users" on "users"."Id" = "mediaFam"."FK_UserId"
INNER JOIN "mediaDetails" on "mediaDetailsFam"."FK_MediaId"  = "media"."Id" 
INNER JOIN "publishedQueue" on "publishedQueueFam"."FK_MediaId" = "media"."Id"
INNER JOIN "publishedVersions" on "publishedVersionsFam"."FK_PublishedQueueId" = "publishedQueue"."Id"
INNER JOIN "mediaType" on "mediaType"."Id" = "mediaFam"."FK_MediaType"  limit 40;
```

I get errors:

```
**Error: ERROR 201 (22000): Illegal data. Expected length of at least 114 bytes, but had 63 (state=22000,code=201)**
```

However when I comment out  the next line

```
"mediaTypeFam"."ParentDirectory"||'/'||"publishedVersionsFam"."S3InputPath" as "PackageOutput"
```

The query executes successfully!!
Whereas both "mediaTypeFam"."ParentDirectory" and "publishedVersionsFam"."S3InputPath" are VARCHAR type.

Now when I **un**comment the next line

```
"mediaTypeFam"."ParentDirectory"||'/'||"publishedVersionsFam"."S3InputPath" as "PackageOutput"
```

and only comment

```
"publishedQueueFam"."InSync" as "In Sync",
```

where "publishedQueueFam"."InSync" is of BOOLEAN type. The query also executes successfully

But when both lines **are present!!** Phoenix query server gives me:

```
**Error: ERROR 201 (22000): Illegal data. Expected length of at least 114 bytes, but had 63 (state=22000,code=201)**
```

Needless I did a lot of work to pin point possible cause and reproduce the error. And a real-life and virtual-online lot of research effort for the possible cause and remedy for this error.

Thank you for your input

Comment: I temporarily used VARCHAR for BOOLEAN types. Wish someone would resolve this random issue!